# Wordpress Page URL

Tags: permalinks, urls

How can I edit the structure of a Wordpress page url to follow this format:

mysite.com/services/doggrooming

Every time I click on the edit permalink button on the page, the first "/" after "services" gets deleted automatically.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Create a top level page with the slug `services`. Then create a page with the slug `doggrooming` and set the parent page to the Services page. WordPress will handle the URL structure if you're using pretty permalinks.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help! Please click the check mark if this solved the issue so that the question will be removed from the unanswered queue.